# Error while passing variables to a command

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run an azure command in linux bash:

```
azcopy copy '$localfilepath' 'https://$storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/$filesharename/$filename?$SAStoken'
```

I have the following variables:

```
export localfilepath="/test/mylocation/"
export filename="myfile.txt"
export storageaccountname="mystorageaccount"
export filesharename="myfileshare"
export SAStoken="?sv=2021-10-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlakopx&se=2025-06-01T18:33:00Z&st=2023-09-15T10:33:00Z&spr=https&sig=wsdDda3%2BAVZkf0LgjfI2hQtcNz4p6Iupf7BJDvvugXR4%3D"
```

When I run the mentioned command, I get this error:

```
azcopy copy '$localfilepath' 'https://$storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/$filesharename/$filename?$SAStoken'

failed to parse user input due to error: azure files only supports the use of SAS token authentication
```

If I replace all the variables for the values the command works fine, so I guess there is some issue when I try to use the $SAStoken, which is not being interpreted as it should.

Can anyone help?

Comment: use dbl-quotes on variable values, `i.e. `"$myVar"`. Good luck.

Comment: Within single quotes, `$...` does not get expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

After reading the suggested post I made it work like this:

```
azcopy copy "$localfilepath/$filename" 'https://'"$storageaccountname"'.file.core.windows.net/'"$filesharename/$filename$SAStoken"
```

Comment: Try this: `"azcopy copy '$localfilepath' 'https://$storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/$filesharename/$filename?$SAStoken'"`

Inside the `""` string, `'` is just another character, and does *not* introduce a new string, so variables expand as expected.